# Create system oauth for API based on my service

Tags: node.js, api, express, oauth

I would like to develop a system that can help any developer to create an application based to my API.

My problem is authentication.
I have see (for example) as work google with your services; I would like create an system of oauth (private) such as google (concept) that an developer, after sign to my portal, get APP ID and APP SECRET.

When developer self create these credentials, can use for call API based to https.

My API are developed by nodejs and express system.

I say which way is more stable for create an system robust for this scenario.

Thanks for any support. Any idea is appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try http://passportjs.org/, it can work as a middleware with express.

Comment: thank you for reply. I am testing some example and work correctly.